# 1066MHz memory in 3.33GHz 6-core Mac Pro 5,1

Tags: memory, mac-pro

I have gotten conflicting messages about whether or not 1066MHz memory will work in my Mac Pro 5,1 (6-core Westmere 3.33GHz).   As opposed to 1333MHz.   (Both DDDR3, ECC, 240-pin).   Will it function at all ?   Will it slow the machine down ?   If I try installing it, what's the best way to verify it's functioning properly and whether or not it's slowing down the memory bus and/or processor speed ?

Comment: If you already have it, why not try it? If you don't, why not get the correct 1333? There's more to slow down an old Mac Pro than RAM speed - HDs, SATA II, any OS above El Cap,  etc etc...

Comment: Will it work?  Possibly.  Will it slow down your machine? Yes.  It calls for 1333MHz, so anything slower than that will slow things down.  By how much?  You'll have to benchmark it.  What's the best way to test?  Run [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) or Apple Diagnostics.  *Why not just get the right memory the spec calls for and avoid all the unnecessary uncertainty?*

Comment: Yeah, I've got it in hand, good point.  "Any OS above ElCap" ?   I was planning to try to get this machine up to Mojave, so hope it's not up to it, even though technically supprts it (with a new GPU).

Comment: Because I have 3x8GB of the 1066MHz stuff, in an old 4,1 that might get scrapped (doubt anyone will want it).   The 5,1 has 3x4GB of the 1333MHz stuff.   It's $100+ to buy 3x8GB of 1333MHz.

Comment: This page (https://macperformanceguide.com/Reviews-MacProWestmere-Memory.html) says "The 3.33GHz 6-core model specifies 1333MHz memory. However, I installed the OWC 4GB 1066MHz modules in it, and it worked like a charm. This could save you a ton of money if you already own 4GB or 8GB modules. My measurement of the memory bandwidth showed only a small difference in memory bandwidth—about 10%—not to be confused with real-world performance, for which I measured no difference at all."

Comment: @Allan thanks for link to memtest86.  I guess that'll confirm the 1066MHz modules are fully functional, but will it give a notion of how much if any it lows machine down ?

Comment: I was half-joking about Mojave. It's OK ..ish. I found both Sierras to be hideous & couldn't wait to be rid of them. I still think APFS & Time Machine local backups are more trouble than they're worth.  I've still an old 3,1 which is just fine on El Cap. BTW, the About This Mac>Memory will show you if there are any issues with any stick, but idk what it will say if the speeds are 'wrong'. These show no errors right now, but I've seen them in the past - https://i.stack.imgur.com/he6jt.png

Comment: Yeah, I created a new partition and put HighSierra on it, and it seems a bit clunkier than ElCap; I especially notice it opening about twenty 50MB image files at once in Preview.   I guess I'll go to Mojave from HS and leave ElCap in place.   Wrestling now with how to deal with the non-functonality of StartupManager (option yet at startup) because of the un-supported "metal" GPU I have to install for Mojave.

Comment: I'd be tempted to put El Cap & Mojave on different drives, not just partitions. Mojave will insist on APFS, El Cap can't read that. [APFS was optional in HS, but compulsory in Mojave]. I'd also splash out on a properly supported Mac-flashed Metal GPU. It will save a lot of trouble in the long run.

Comment: All Mac-flahsed metal GPUs are pretty expensive, but you're right it'd save a lot of trouble; I am messing with rEFInd to try to get around the lack of a boot screen (option key on startup) but it is a mess and developer is unresponsive.

Comment: Why would separate drives (for ElCap and Mojave) get around the problem of ElCap not being able to "see" Mojave ?   (So can't switch from ElCap to Mojave in SystemPrefs->StartupDisk).

Comment: tbh, it's just something I've always done. I have Boot Camp on a separate drive too. I'm not sure what practical benefit it has, other than drive management, HD swaps etc. Right now I have 6 drives in mine, with an OS on each. I juggle them at boot & each hides the others in fstab so as not to confuse Spotlight.